# Linq to SQL - Default Insert/Update/Delete functions not present

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Using VS2010 and SQL express 2005, Ive created a database, created a simple table, added the database to VS2010, dragged the table i wish to query into a new 'Linq To SQL' class.

Now, selecting works as expected - totally great.

However it has not generated the Remove() method, `mydb.SumbitChanges()` does nothing after amending a retrieved object, so I have obviously missed a vital step.

I have not defined anything to do updating or removing, but assumed it did this 'out the box'.

Can anyone offer any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved - I had not set a primary key on the table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link how you do insert, update and delete:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb386931.aspx